# class to create array and fetch values

Tags: php, oop

I've really been trying my best to convert my half decade worth of average skilled PHP knowledge to rely more on OOP, but I've been having a lot more difficult time of grasping the practicality of classes.

I think there's something I do frequently that would be a good, simple case of how to use classes and would help me to get started.

Currently when I want to do something like make an "object" that stores user data I'll do this...

```
$user=/* some work to pull from SQL the user's saved information*/;

echo "Welcome ".$user['firstname']." ".$user['lastname']."!";
```

Which works fine in that case, but gets ugly when I have to do...

```
$user=/* some work to pull from SQL the user's saved information*/;

function echo_welcome() {
   global $user;
   echo "Welcome ".$user['firstname']." ".$user['lastname']."!";
}

echo_welcome();
```

Basically I'm looking to stop using global since I now know that it's (mostly) evil.

How would I accomplish this using classes?  I'd expect the class to generate the user information just once from the SQL, and then let me access values from the user array inside and outside of other functions.

Bonus points if you can show me how to change things inside the class after it's created.  For example, I do sometimes have to force changes to the user information depending on other conditions.  For example...

```
if ($site_settings['allUsersNoAccess']) $user['noAccess']=true;

if ($user['noAccess']) die("Go away");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change:

```
function echo_welcome() {
   global $user;
   echo "Welcome ".$user['firstname']." ".$user['lastname']."!";
}
```

to:

```
function echo_welcome($user) {
   echo "Welcome ".$user['firstname']." ".$user['lastname']."!";
}
```

and pass $user to the function when you call it:

```
echo_welcome($user);
```

The other question is not clear: when you do `$user['noAccess']=true;` you *are* changing the user object.

If you want to do it inside of a class, you can use the constructor to save reference to the user object and then use it in the methods, example:

```
class MyClass {

    private    $user;

    function __construct($user){  
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    function do_something(){
        echo $user['firstname'];
    }

    function setUserName($new_name){
        $user['first_name'] = $new_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I realize that this is one way to do it.  But I was just giving a VERY simplified version of the type of functions I'm using.  For example, I have functions that will only ever need the $user array in rare cases.  And sometimes functions that COULD need access to all kinds of objects like the $user array.  I'd hate to have to feed through to these functions every single object that it could possibly need.  I'd end up with things like echo_welcome($site_settings,$user,$page_settings,$browserInfo,$lotsOfOtherThings);

Comment: @StevenJenkins In this case, what about creating a class variable called user, assigned it only once (in the constructor) and then you can use it anywhere inside the class.

Comment: I think this sounds like what I need to do.  But I simply don't know how to go about creating that.  Can you edit your answer and show me what that would look like?

Comment: So then how would I call $user['firstname'] outside of the class?  Something like $MyClass->do_something->firstname? Also, what if from outside of the class I wanted to change $user['firstname'] to something else?  Then have that change be reflected later on the next time I accessed $user['firstname']?

Comment: You have the $user object outside the class so you can access it directly and change it. And yes, if you change it outside the class you'll see the changes inside the class too since it's the same object.

Comment: I'm sorry to be a pain here... but could you show me the exact code you'd use to access $user['firstname'] from outside the class you wrote?

Comment: @StevenJenkins from outside the class you *have* the object so you can simply do `$user['firstname'] = "blabla";`

Comment: @StevenJenkins if you want to access `$user` **through** the class, then better create access functions, for example: `function setUserName($name){...` I'll add it to the example above.